# SP07 - Get items from choice textbox and insert into DropDownList (-programmatically-)

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server, development, 2007, ssom

I have a **list** (WayBill) with **column**(ProdyctType). I need to get these items and input then into **dropDownList**.

**This is my columnType in SP07:**

[image]

**This is my code:**

```
  protected override void CreateChildControls()
        {
            Label lblProducType = new Label();
            lblProducType.Text = "ProducType";
            DropDownList ddProducType = new DropDownList();
            ddProducType.Items.Add("-- Choose ProducType --");
            ddProducType.Width = 300;

            using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://sf-spsdev02/TestSite/"))
            {
                using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                {
                    web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                    SPList wayList = web.Lists["WayBill"];

                    //maybe use SPField class HERE ?

                }
            }


            lblProject = new Label();
            lblProject.Text = "Project";
            ddProject = new DropDownList();
            ddProject.Width = 300;
            ddProject.Items.Add("-- Choose project --");
            GetProject();
```

Comment: You have `ProductType` in your screenshot, `ProducType` in your code, and `ProdyctType` in your text above. Which spelling are you using?

Answer (score 0):

This answer is basing off your original question's code

...

```
 using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://sf-spsdev02/TestSite/"))
        {
            using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
            {
                web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                SPList wayList = web.Lists["WayBill"];

                SPFieldChoice field = (SPFieldChoice)wayList.Fields["ProducType"];
                foreach (string choice in field.Choices)
                {
                   ddProducType.Items.Add(choice);
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: Give me this error : Value does not fall within the expected range.

Comment: on which line? You may have just mispelled the "ProductType", which I did too, following your original post...try my edit

Comment: Not working, After comment this code, Web Part is working...

Comment: can you provide more information than that? What is the webpart doing? Which line does it error on? Did you change the field name? check all your variables. Try my edit...

Comment: Where is your edit? Code is the same..

Comment: I edited the fieldname, which is `ProducType` correct? Do you have the correct spelling? Please check all the spelling in my code to match your spelling and try again. If you check and get another error, please let me know what error and where it occurred.